# Id.exe has stopped working while building SDL-project in Code::Blocks

Tags: sdl, codeblocks

I've done everything as described in here: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php 
But when I try to build the project it says that id.exe has stopped working. What's going on?

Comment: Show us your code and build log.

Comment: Code is downloaded from that page, so I don't think that it's wrong.

Comment: Ok. But we also need to see the build log.

Comment: -------------- Build: Debug in SF (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Users\Juho\Documents\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86 -o bin\Debug\SF.exe obj\Debug\Downloads\01_hello_SDL.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  
C:\Users\Juho\Documents\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86/SDL2main.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main]+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here

Comment: Warning: .drectve `/manifestdependency:"type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'" /DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 255 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like you used wrong download link. You need  `SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz`.

Comment: I checked it, but the file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was, but it work's now.
I just installed SDL2 as devpak and it helped.